# Is it bad to publish a scientific paper with wrong results?

Tags: publications, research-process, ethics, errors-erratum

I was working during the last year on developing an approach that determines human age class (young or old), but after I got exciting results I've discovered that I made a mistake when implementing some lines of code. I think that the mistake is a bit critical because I was comparing my approach and literature's ones. The mistake I made was during the classification task, where the data was entered in the right way but the experience was badly managed.

What should I do? Do I have to stay quiet or do I have to fix it? Note that the paper is not yet published nor peer reviewed.

Comment: From your question, it's not clear whether your erroneous results have already been peer reviewed and published. Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: The paper is not yet published neither peer reviewed. I will add this information to the question. Thank you @Pont

Comment: So, what keeps you from correcting the error before submitting?

Comment: If it's wrong and you know it, it is unethical to try to pass it off as fine.  "Negative results", which is in your tags, is a different thing.  Something like "Theory X predicts that Y happens at rate Z, but our data rules out Z as the correct rate" would be a negative result: you had a theory and a hypothesis to start with and end up refuting it.

Comment: @damian my exact case is that i am a master student, and as i said i was working during a whole year on developping the mensionned approach. The problem is that after i submitted my master thesis (i didn't present it yet this is programmed to be in the 30 comming days) i discovered that mistake which was accidently confirmed it (he didn't reviewed the code lines). So basing those results we deicided to publish an article. What should I do?

Comment: @zibadawa that's not a negative result (which in itself is an helpful term and should be avoided). Proving  a theory wrong is a very useful positive finding.

Comment: Incidentally, Retraction Watch had a post about "Retraction relutance" yesterday: http://retractionwatch.com/2015/12/05/weekend-reads-retraction-reluctance-worthless-papers-and-stats-too-many-phds/

Comment: @damian: said 'retraction reluctance' linked above. It's a kind of laziness towards retraction, but not really a fraud.

Comment: "Is it bad to lie?" Um, yes. Yes, it is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in German, the term for scientist is *Wissenschaftler*, meaning *knowledge maker*. I guess the point in a *scientific* context is: Do not make knowledge worse when publishing. Make it better, or else you're not a *Wissenschaftler*.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Publishing things that you know are erroneous is a good way to get a really bad scientific reputation. Depending on how severe it is, it might go so far as to be labelled fraud and formally sanctioned, basically killing your career.

If it's important, then yes, you need to fix it.

If it's not published yet, then fix it before you publish it.  If it's published, then you will need to submit a correction or possibly even a retraction.  Good scientists do this, and [it's much better to acknowledge your errors and retract than to have others expose you as a liar](http://retractionwatch.com/2015/06/16/life-after-retraction-in-many-cases-its-forgive-and-forget/).

Comment: I appreciate your answer i will certainly fix the mistake. What should I do about my master thesis that was submited before i discover the issue?

Comment: Find out if your university will allow you to submit a correction. Many will allow this. If not, at least make sure you note the existence of the error in the follow on peer-reviewed publication, which will be understood to supersede it in any case.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better to do so.
Because when you have results which are inaccurate or which are wrong, people who have access to that paper will surely have to redo the results and even the whole paper (study) if necessary. 
By doing this, some of the missed concepts of the study may be filled up during the second study.
I had a task to come up with a term paper within a semester. Little did I know that the results were inaccurate. My lecturer instructed me to redo the paper and to my surprise I found new information which I didn't find during the first study.

Comment: I disagree. It's nothing more than an act of academic misdemeanor. The OP clearly knows there has been an error and its his responsibility to correct it.
I couldn't understand how you can actually improve our current understanding of a subject by pumping in false information on intention.

Comment: Homework assignments aren't really comparable with peer-reviewed publications so I don't see the relevance of your answer.